# Periodicity of an infinitely differentiable function

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, fourier-analysis

> Consider $f:[-\pi,\pi] \to \mathbb{C}$ be an infinitely differentiable function with $f^{(n)}(-\pi) = f^{(n)}(\pi)$ for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$.
>   Is this a periodic function ?

I think it is a periodic function but not sure.

I can only infer that its derivative is periodic: since for each $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$, the derivative starts repeat itself at $\pi$, $f^{(n)}(-\pi) = f^{(n)}(\pi)$. but what happen for the original function (I mean without taking derivative, can I still say this function is a periodic function)?

Comment: What does it even mean for a function with domain $[-\pi,\pi]$ to be periodic with period $2\pi$?

Comment: And even if $f$ is analytic, but you don't know that $f(-\pi)=f(\pi)$, then you can't say that $f$ is periodic.  For instance, $f(x)=x+\cos x$ is a possibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**: This is the answer for the first version of the question.

If `period` means `the smallest period` the answer is: no. Constant functions  are counterexamples.

Comment: Thanks for reply, @Kola B. but I'm considering an infinite differentiable function, I don't see how constant function fits this criterion.

Comment: If $f(x) = c$ is constant, then $f^{(n)}(x) = 0$ for all $n \ge 1$.

Comment: Constant functions are infinitely differentiable, all derivatives are $0$.

Comment: Thank you guys. @JimmyK4542, and Henrik, But it start getting confuse me, so can I say that the polynomial be an infinitely differentiable? e.g., $f(x) := x^2$ (I was thinking $x^2$ only can be differentiated twice only.)

Comment: Yep, a polynomial is infinitely differentiable.

Comment: Thank you @Clement C. I got it :)